# Arrays logical error

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote the following code for solving a problem but it doesn't work. The link to the question is [**here**](http://codingbat.com/prob/p134022).

```
  public boolean linearIn(int[] outer, int[] inner) {

    boolean result = false;

        if(inner.length == 0)
            return true;

        index: for(int x: inner) {
                    for(int y: outer) {
                        if(x==y) {
                            result = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            result = false;
                            break index;
                        }
                    }
                }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't explain anything. Please describe exactly what this code is supposed to do, and what it's doing that doesn't work.

Comment: A) What is the problem you're trying to solve? B) What is the expected result? C) What are you seeing instead? D) Do *you* have any ideas on what might be wrong? Note that questions should be **self-contained**; links are fine but following them must be *optional* for understanding an answering the question. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question (the same principle applies even to non-code links).

Comment: the link to the question is [**here**](http://codingbat.com/prob/p134022)

Comment: @nick-s: **Again**, questions on SO are meant to stand alone. External links can be modified, moved, deleted, etc., rendering the question completely useless for anyone else in the future. Put the *whole* question *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the else part of. As you can't conclude that the element in not in the inner array ***if just one comparison fails***:

```
if(x==y) {
 result = true;  // ele present.
 break;
} else { 
 result = false; // can't conclude ele is absent..you might find it later.
 break index;
}
```

To fix this you might do:

```
public boolean linearIn(int[] outer, int[] inner) {

        for(int x: inner) {
                // assume x is absent.
                boolean result = false;
                for(int y: outer) {
                        // x found in outer.
                        if(x==y) {
                                // make result positive.
                                result = true;
                                // no need to look any further.
                                break;
                        }
                }
                // at this point not all elements of inner are 
                // tested for presence in outer. But one missing ele
                // would mean we return false.
                if(result == false) return false;
        }
        // all ele of inner are present in outer..return true.
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the complexity should be O(n), an hypothetical code:

```
public boolean linearIn (int[] outer, int[] inner) {

 int in=0;
    for(int i :outer){
        if(in==inner.length) return true;
        if(inner[in]==i)
            in++;}
    if(in==inner.length)return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The arrays are sorted and the solution should be O(n).

Comment: sorry i didn't understand that the complexity should be O(n) I change the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must make an O(n) solution, yours is O(n<sup>2</sup>). You need just three lines (OK, cheating a bit):

```
int j = 0;
for (int in : inner) while (outer[j] != in) if (++j == outer.length) return false;
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to loop over the outer and loop the inner inside the outer
if on the way you see its breaks the rules immediately return false
if at the end the index of the inner looped over all the array return true otherwise false.

```
public boolean linearIn(int[] outer, int[] inner) {
    int i, j;
    // loop over the outer
    for(i = 0, j =0; i < outer.length && j < inner.length; i++) {
       // move to the last same value on the outer
       while(i < outer.length-1 && outer[i] == outer[i+1]) {
           i++;
       }
       // move to the last same value on the inner
       while(j < inner.length-1 && inner[j] == inner[j+1]) {
           j++;
       }
       // immediate false
       if(inner[j] < outer[i]) {
           return false;
       }
       // match - move to the next inner
       if(inner[j] == outer[i]) {
           j++;
       }
    }
    if(j == inner.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```